# How to do Join in Solr Collections?

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, spring-data

I have two **solr** collections

1. Collection-A
2. Collection-B

I need to join these two collections and get one final result with both collections data.

**Collection-A**:

```
[
   {
      "uuId": "000000",
      "oName": "IN",
      "paId": "IN01",
      "pName": "ABCD"
   },
   {
      "uuId": "111111",
      "oName": "IN",
      "paId": "IN02",
      "pName": "DEF"
   }
]
```

**Collection-B**:

```
[
   {
      "uuId": "333333",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "pId": "IN01",
      "pName": "ABCD"
   },
   {
      "uuId": "444444",
      "firstName": "Saman",
      "lastName": "Lee",
      "pId": "IN02",
      "pName": "DEF"
   }
]
```

**Expected results:**

```
[
   {
      "uuId": "000000",
      "oName": "IN",
      "paId": "IN01",
      "pName": "ABCD",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
   },
   {
      "uuId": "111111",
      "oName": "IN",
      "paId": "IN02",
      "pName": "DEF",
      "firstName": "Saman",
      "lastName": "Lee"
   }
]
```

**Solr UI:**

On Collection-A:
I have added ***fq -> {!join from=pId fromIndex=Collection-B to=paId}***

I am able to get the results for this, But not getting the Collection-B's firstName,lastName. (Expected results)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the joins only to filter the data from solr.
You cannot use the solr join to fetch the data from another collection.

Please refer the below link for the same.
[Solr Join across collection](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/other-parsers.html#joining-across-collections)

Comment: Ok, So any other way to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know solr in not meant to use like RDBMS...so either you should create a single collection which has all the relevant data or you can try with the parent child structure with solr.